# Django if statements in forms

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to allow a user to upload a file of unknown type through a form and then save it to a folder depending on the type of file it is. I was hoping I could use 'if' statements, but I can't make them work inside the form.
I currently just have direct upload paths:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    Priority_Upload = models.FileField(default='priority', upload_to='priority/', blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.FileField(default='text', upload_to='text/', blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default', upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    video = models.FileField(default='video', upload_to='videos/',blank=True, null=True)
    large_video = models.FileField(default='large_video', upload_to='large_video/', blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    # user owns the post, but post doesn't own the user.

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I'd like to do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    Priority_Upload = models.FileField(default='priority', upload_to='priority/', blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    if(*image ends in .txt*)
        content = models.FileField(default='text', upload_to='text/', blank=True, null=True)
    if(*image ends in .png*)
        image = models.ImageField(default='default', upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like

```
if str(image).endswith('txt'):
   *Your condition*
```

Comment: So 'if' statements function in forms? Because when I add that, it looks like it just never enters the if statement. I added this line and had it print out 'success' if it entered the loop, then uploaded a file that ended with a .txt. It just seems to have passed over it, so I was wondering if perhaps forms don't allow you to check the values of filefields?